Making a macro for a list or array in Latex
I want to make a list with values I can refer to in my code. For example, say I was working with my_list = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} or any identical forms. I want to be able to input my_list[1] and have the list spit out 1 (or 2) as the case may be. It is not necessary for the values to work with arithmetic. I don't know how to go about this and Google searches and ChatGPT give very little information and error-ridden code respectively. What do I do?

The listofitems package does this.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}

\begin{document}
\newcommand\mylistraw{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}

\readlist*\mylist{\mylistraw}

The third list item is \mylist[3].
\end{document}

It can also handle multi-dimensional arrays.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems}

\begin{document}
\newcommand\mytwoDlistraw{aa, ab\\ba, bb\\ ca,cb}
\setsepchar{\\/,}
\readlist*\mylist{\mytwoDlistraw}

The list item in the second column of the second row is \mylist[2,2].
\end{document}



If you just want containers to extract items from, it's quite easy with expl3.
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\newarray}{mO{}}
 {
  \clist_clear_new:c { l_vector_array_#1_clist }
  \clist_set:cn { l_vector_array_#1_clist } {#2}
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\addtoarray}{mm}
 {
  \clist_if_exist:cTF { l_vector_array_#1_clist }
   {
    \clist_put_right:cn { l_vector_array_#1_clist } { #2 }
   }
   {
    \msg_error:nnn { vector/array } { array-not-exist } { #1 }
   }
 }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\getfromarray}{mm}
 {
  \clist_item:cn { l_vector_array_#1_clist } {#2}
 }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\countarray}{m}
 {
  \clist_count:c { l_vector_array_#1_clist }
 }

\msg_new:nnnn { vector/array } { array-not-exist }
 {
  Array~'#1'~does~not~exist
 }
 {
  You~asked~for~array~'#1',~which~doesn't~exist
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\newarray{first}
\addtoarray{first}{1,2,3}
\addtoarray{first}{4,5}

\newarray{second}[a,b,c,d,e]

\addtoarray{third}{x,y,z} % error!

\getfromarray{first}{3} (should print 3)

\getfromarray{second}{4} (should print d)

\getfromarray{second}{-2} (should print d)

X\getfromarray{first}{6}X (should print nothing between XX)

The array \texttt{first} has \countarray{first} items

\end{document}

You see that with a negative argument you get the item obtained by counting from the end.

The error message coming from trying to add to a unallocated array will be
! Package vector/array Error: Array 'third' does not exist

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...

l.50 \addtoarray{third}{x,y,z}
                               % error!
? h

You asked for array 'third', which doesn't exist

?

Note that, if you ask for an item that's not available, say \getfromarray{first}{6} you get nothing.

expl3
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_node_row_seq  
\seq_new:N \l_node_tmp_seq 
\cs_set:Npn \GetArray #1 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_node_row_seq {;} {#1}
  \int_step_inline:nn{\seq_count:N \l_node_row_seq}
  {
    \seq_if_exist:cF {l_node_row_##1_seq}
    {
      \seq_new:c {l_node_row_##1_seq}
    }
    \exp_args:Ncx\seq_set_from_clist:Nn {l_node_row_##1_seq} {\seq_item:Nn \l_node_row_seq{##1}}
  }
}

\cs_set:Npn \PrintArray [#1][#2] {
  \tl_if_empty:nTF { #1 }
  {
    \tl_if_empty:nTF { #2 }
    {
      \seq_use:Nn \l_node_row_seq {,}
    }
    {
      \int_step_inline:nn{\seq_count:N \l_node_row_seq}
      {
        \seq_put_right:Nn \l_node_tmp_seq {\seq_item:cn {l_node_row_##1_seq}{#2}}
      }
      \seq_use:Nn \l_node_tmp_seq {,}
    }
  }
  {
    \tl_if_empty:nTF {#2}
    {
      \seq_use:cn {l_node_row_#1_seq}{,}
    }
    {
      \seq_item:cn {l_node_row_#1_seq}{#2}
    }
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\GetArray
{
  A,B,C;
  D,E,F;
  G,H,I
}
\PrintArray[][]\par 
\PrintArray[1][]\par 
\PrintArray[][2]\par 
\PrintArray[1][2]  


\end{document}

tikz
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\def\myarray{{
{"A","B","C"},
{"D","E","F"},
{"G","H","I"}
}}

\pgfmathparse{\myarray[1][2]}\pgfmathresult

\end{document}


You can use expl3 and have LaTeX via a macro
\DefineIndexedListMacro{\macro}{⟨comma list⟩}
define a macro
\macro{⟨index number⟩}{⟨tokens in case comma list did not have an ⟨index number⟩th element⟩}
from the comma list where internally \str_case:nnF is used for selecting the list item.
For the sake of having fun I added integer-evaluation via \int_eval:n.
In the course of defining the macro internally \clist_item:nn is used. Thus, if present, explicit surrounding space tokens and after that, if present, one level of surrounding curly braces are removed from each element of the comma list.  If after removing surrounding spaces (if present) an element of the comma list is empty, it is not taken into account. Thus, if you wish an empty list-element to be taken into account, you need to denote it via a pair of matching curly braces {}.
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\msg_new:nnnn { MyStuff } { command-already-defined }
 { Control~sequence~#1~already~defined. }
 {
   This~is~a~coding~error. \\ \\
   The~macro~#3~of~module~MyStuff~has~been~asked~to~create~a~new~control~sequence~’#1’~
   but~this~name~has~already~been~used~elsewhere. \\ \\
   The~current~meaning~is:\\
   \ \ #2
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \DefineIndexedListMacro #1#2 {
  \cs_if_exist:NTF #1 {\use_i:nn}{\use_ii:nn}
  {
    \msg_error:nnxxx { MyStuff } { command-already-defined }
    { \token_to_str:N #1 } { \token_to_meaning:N #1 }{ \token_to_str:N \DefineIndexedListMacro}
  }{
    \cs_set:Npn #1 ##1  {{##1}{\exp_not:N \exp_not:n {\clist_item:nn {#2}{##1}}}}
    \cs_gset_protected:Npx #1 ##1##2 {
      \exp_not:n { \exp_args:NNo \exp_args:No \str_case:nnF }
        { \exp_not:N \int_eval:n {##1} }
        { \int_step_function:nnN {1} {\clist_count:n {#2}} #1 }
        { \exp_not:N \exp_not:n {##2}}
    }
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

%\newcommand\SomeList{Already defined!}

\DefineIndexedListMacro \SomeList {One, Two, Three, \LaTeX\space Four}

%\show\SomeList

\begin{document}

\SomeList{1}{!!! List does not have entry 1 !!!}

\SomeList{2}{!!! List does not have entry 2 !!!}

\SomeList{3}{!!! List does not have entry 3 !!!}

\SomeList{4}{!!! List does not have entry 4 !!!}

\SomeList{2*(3-9)+15}{!!! List does not have entry \the\numexpr2*(3-9)+15\relax\space!!!}

\SomeList{2*(3-9)+27}{!!! List does not have entry \the\numexpr2*(3-9)+27\relax\space!!!}

\SomeList{5}{!!! List does not have entry 5 !!!}

\SomeList{-4}{!!! List does not have entry -4 !!!}

% \SomeList{Huh?}{!!! List does not have entry Huh? !!!}

\end{document}


